# Invoking in the terminal

Tags: shell, terminal, python

I have downloaded Python 3 and a terminal emulator. But when I type python3 in the terminal, it says "not found".

How do I run the python interactive shell inside the terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first have to set the environment settings in your device to access the python 3.

**To use, make the script executable and run from the shell**:

```
chmod a+x standalone_python.sh
./standalone_python.sh
```

or, if that doesn't work (and it may not, depending on filesystem) just:

```
sh /sdcard/standalone_python.sh
```

The script at time of writing looks like this:

```
#! /bin/sh

export EXTERNAL_STORAGE=/mnt/storage
PYTHONPATH=/mnt/storage/com.googlecode.pythonforandroid/extras/python
PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/data/data/com.googlecode.pythonforandroid/files/python/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload
export PYTHONPATH
export TEMP=/mnt/storage/com.googlecode.pythonforandroid/extras/python/tmp
export PYTHON_EGG_CACHE=$TEMP
export PYTHONHOME=/data/data/com.googlecode.pythonforandroid/files/python
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/data/data/com.googlecode.pythonforandroid/files/python/lib
/data/data/com.googlecode.pythonforandroid/files/python/bin/python "$@"
```

**Original Source :**

https://code.google.com/p/python-for-android/wiki/RunPythonFromShell

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are on Android so why you don't just download the app already optimized? There's and a fine editor too. When you install it from GooglePlay you just tap on console and you are ready.

Comment: Yeah. In fact that's the way I installed python. But where's the fun in there? :P